# How to print out Boolean values if fields exists in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

Suppose I have a find function like this one:

```
cursor_test=db.person.find({ "properties.name": { "$exists": True, "$ne": False } })
        for docu in cursor_test:
            pprint(docu)
```

The `pprint` would definitely print out the document, however, I would like to get a boolean output, `True or False`. If I just try to print out `cursor_test` it will print out the cursor address.

I am trying to do the find field if exist or not so I can update it inserting the new field in a document structured like this:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "582fc95"
},
"type": "Feature",
"route_id": "880801",
"geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinate": [
        [
            120.9834301,
            14.60350785
        ]
    ]
},
"properties": {
    "name": "Retolan"
    }
}
```

Bottomline, I want to check if the field exists by knowing its boolean value against a conditional statement before I update the document. :)

Comment: You don't have to get the boolean value and then update. You can atomically do it with update command. Something like `db.person.update({ "properties.name": { "$exists": True, "$ne": False } }, {"$set":{"properties.name":"some value"}})`. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: @Veeram yes that should be okay. However for testing purposes I would just like to know so I can just print it out on the console. But if there really is no possible way to do it then I'll just back my db up then. 

Comment: You can use `find_one` which will return document if it exists or else `None`. So compare the value against the `None` and print the boolean value on the console for testing purposes. More here http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one.